# Android NDK compilation without sysroot

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, native, cross-compiling

I am trying to compile the source code for multiple architectures and multiple API levels of Android NDK based on the compilation flags (by dynamically passing path of Application.mk to the ndk-build command). It was going fine till r12. Now I was trying to update my build system to latest NDK r15c and found that it's taking headers from "android-ndk/sysroot/..." path instead of depending on the APP_PLATFORM flag from Application.mk file

```
APP_PLATFORM                   := android-19
```

***Logs for r12b NDK:***

```
-I/data/android/android-ndk-r10d/platforms/android-19/arch-arm/usr/include
```

Above include path is present when I try verbose logs for ndk-build (V=1) .

***Logs for r15c NDK:***

```
--sysroot
/home/airwatch/Android/android-ndk/sysroot
-isystem
/home/airwatch/Android/android-ndk/sysroot/usr/include/arm-linux-androideabi
```

Above include path is present when I try verbose logs for r15c NDK.

It will not be possible to configure [Standalone Toolchain](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/standalone_toolchain.html) due to my project requirements. Is there anyway to get rid of this sysroot?

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: I guess you are confused by absence of `android-XX` component in path. It is perfectly fine for r15c since it uses [unified headers](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/master/docs/UnifiedHeaders.md) by default. And now target API level is configured by `-D__ANDROID_API__=$API` compilation definition.

Comment: Issue is few systemcalls in native are introduced in android-21. But we support below versions also. we use different system call in case of android-19 and android-21 and above. Unified headers are not a solution as we support pre-Lollipop as well. We have different builds for different versions. All these days it was going well as the headers will be properly picked up with APP_PLATFORM, but not now.

Comment: ask @DanAlbert  he is one of the core NDK developers

Comment: Unified headers and the libraries you build against are orthogonal concepts. `$NDK/sysroot` is the unified headers and is what you should be using when *compiling*. When *linking*, you should still be using `$NDK/platforms/android-$API/arch-$ARCH`. We do have a doc explaining how to use unified headers in a custom build system: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/master/docs/UnifiedHeaders.md#Supporting-Unified-Headers-in-Your-Build-System.

I'm still not sure I've actually understood your problem though. Can you provide a concrete example of what didn't work?

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned in comments above here is full explain: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/master/docs/UnifiedHeaders.md

> **Unified Headers**
>
> Before NDK r14, we had a set of libc headers for each API version. In
>   many cases these headers were incorrect. Many exposed APIs that didn‘t
>   exist, and others didn’t expose APIs that did.
>
> In NDK r14 (as an opt in feature) we unified these into a single set
>   of headers, called unified headers. This single header path is used
>   for every platform level. API level guards are handled with #ifdef.
>   These headers can be found in prebuilts/ndk/headers.
>
> Unified headers are built directly from the Android platform, so they
>   are up to date and correct (or at the very least, any bugs in the NDK
>   headers will also be a bug in the platform headers, which means we're
>   much more likely to find them).
>
> In r15 unified headers are used by default. In r16, the old headers
>   have been removed.
>
> **Known Issues**
>
> - Standalone toolchains using GCC are not supported out of the box. To
>     use GCC, pass -D__ANDROID_API__=$API when compiling. Note: this is not
>     something we will be fixing.
>
> **Supporting Unified Headers in Your Build**
>   System
>
> 1. Unified headers require only a few changes compared to using the
>      deprecated NDK headers. For reference, this patch added support to
>      ndk-build: https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/239934/
>
> The compile time `sysroot` is now $NDK/sysroot. Previously this was
>   $NDK/platforms/android-$API/arch-$ARCH.
>
> 2. Pass `-isystem $NDK/sysroot/usr/include/$TRIPLE` when compiling. The
>      triple has the following mapping:
>
> Arch    Triple
>   ARM     arm-linux-androideabi
>   ARM64   aarch64-linux-android
>   MIPS    mipsel-linux-android
>   MIPS64  mips64el-linux-android
>   x86     i686-linux-android
>   x86_64  x86_64-linux-android
>
> This is needed for
>   architecture specific headers such as those in asm/ and machine/. We
>   plan to teach Clang's driver to automatically search the architecture
>   specific include directory, but that has yet to be done.
>
> 3. Pass `-D__ANDROID_API__=$API` when compiling. This define used to be
>      provided by `<android/api-level.h>`, but with only one set of headers
>      this is no longer possible. In the future we will look in to adding
>      -mandroid-version or similar to Clang so this is automatic.
> 4. At link time, change nothing. All link time build behavior should
>      match the deprecated headers behavior. `--sysroot` should still point to
>      $NDK/platforms/android-$API/arch-$ARCH/.